# Need help iterating a loop over a list

Tags: python

Can anyone please explain this?

```
userData = 10
emptyList = [0] * userData
for i in emptyList: 
    emptyList[i] = userData
    print(emptyList)
    userData -= 1
```

This in my mind, this code should do something different than it does.

what I am looking for- whatever the value is for userData, I would like it to be indexed in order value in the list emptyList.

This, I thought would give me the set [10, 9, 8] and so on... it doesnt.. it only changes the first variable in each iteration

what did I do wrong?

I made it work another way, userData = 10
emptyList = []
for i in range(userData): 
    emptyList.append(i)
    userData -= 1
    print(emptyList)

but thats not how I like it.. I need the 0 in that set to come out as 10 I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
userData = 10
emptyList = [0] * userData
print emptyList
```

will print

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and in the loop,

```
for i in emptyList:
    print i,
```

will print

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, in all the iterations of the loop, you are changing just the first element of the list. What you should actually have done is

```
userData = 10
emptyList = [0] * userData

for i in range(len(emptyList)):
    emptyList[i] = userData
    userData -= 1
print emptyList
```

**Output**

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

There is a builtin function called `range` which accepts starting value, ending value and the increment value and generates a sequence of values. With that function you can do this in a single line

```
print range(10, 0, -1)  #Python 2
print list(range(10, 0, -1))  #Python 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
for i in emptyList:
```

will give you a loop, setting `i` to each of the values in `emptyList` in turn.

Since *all* of those values are zero, that means `i` will always be zero, hence it will only ever change the first value.

If you want the list `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`, just use the more Pythonic:

```
emptylist = [x for x in range (10, 0, -1)]
```

Comment: this was genuinely helpful.  Does it change if I set the empty list to [1] ?

Comment: @user2962806, yes it craps out with a index error because, at some point, you try to reference `emptyList[10]` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are reading the code like this

```
userData = 10
emptyList = [0] * userData
for i in range(len(emptyList)): # note range and len here
    emptyList[i] = userData
    print(emptyList)
    userData -= 1
```

You can just use

```
emptyList = range(userData, 0, -1)
```

or is it supposed to do something more?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is fundamentally different in Python than other languages - it's more of a for *each* loop (that is, for each element in the iterable, do stuff with it).

If you want to create a list of elements, use `xrange` for Python 2.x or `range` for Python 3.x:

```
emptyList = [i for i in xrange(10, 0, -1)]

emptyList = [i for i in range(10, 0, -1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
for i, j in emptyList:
  emptyList[j] = userData
  userData -= 1
```

Now you get both the value `i` (which you do not care for) and index `j`, which is what you need.

See [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/1967396) - you are not the first person struggling with loops in Python!